# Exporting content to pdf without using iText

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have worked on exporting the html(table)contents to excel using table id. I have used content type like

```
 response.getWriter().write(datatoexport);
 response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test_file.xls");
 response.getWriter().flush();
 response.getWriter().close();
```

Here, datatoexport is the table id.

It is working fine with excel.

But, if I use content type as pdf like

```
 response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test_file.pdf");
```

But, I am getting pdf file is corrupted. Any help?
Without using iText or other jars, How can I achieve it? Especially in IE 8

Comment: You set the content type as `pdf`, but is the actual content `pdf`?

Comment: setting content type as pdf does not make your output as a real pdf file. content-type is just a flag, but not a direct order for the server.

Comment: No. I am writing the table content to pdf as like excel. But I am getting corrupted pdf file. Any help?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov: Then, what else can I do Mr.Rafael? Any help?

Comment: @user3152748 I have posted a detailed answer. Check it, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before sending pdf file to output, you need to generate it on the server side.

To convert your file to PDF I recommend to use OpenOffice in headless mode and [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter).

To run OpenOffice in headless mode (in Windows) run the command (assume you have OpenOfficePortable, installed in `C:\Apps`:

```
"C:\Apps\OpenOfficePortable\OpenOfficePortable.exe" -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard
```

As you have OpenOffice started in headless mode, run a simple working prototype using JODConverter library:

```
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.DocumentConverter;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeConnection;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.SocketOpenOfficeConnection;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.ConnectException;

public class JODConv {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConnectException {

        if (args.length!=2) {
            System.out.println("Usage:\nJODConv <file-to-convert> <pdf-file>");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String sourceFilePath = args[0];
        String destFilePath = args[1];


        File inputFile = new File(sourceFilePath);
        File outputFile = new File(destFilePath);

        // connect to an OpenOffice.org instance running on port 8100
        OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
        connection.connect();

        // convert
        DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
        converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

        // close the connection
        connection.disconnect();
    }       
}
```

Comment: I need to do this in server side. Not in localhost. And without using any external library. I need to use it bro as like excel.

Comment: As you are running open office and your conversion code on the same server, then localhost is acceptable. If conversion code and open office are running on the different servers, then specify the ip-address of the openoffice server, instead of localhost.

Comment: And if you wish to avoid use of any free/opensource libraries, then check [PDF Format Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) and make your own conversion methods.

Comment: IE8, Internet Explorer or other browser are not be related to the conversion task. This task is going to be done on the server, browser runs on the client computer.

Comment: Is there any working examples? I couldn't get the process of JOD Converter.

Comment: did you get an error/exception or what? The code I provided works for me.

Comment: Ya. I would be great if you show some working example bro. I don't know how to do this :(

Comment: have you done steps I described in my answer to make a working prototype? Did it work? If no, what error did you get?